# Send axios fetch to domain name, and resending it to API

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch-api, fastapi

I want to solve a problem with react native and iphone. I have API on Gcloud let say ip 34.xx.xx.xx, and a domain name myapp.com. On domain name myapp.com I have SSL sertificate and https, on ip address i have nginx server with https to but without sertificate. What can i do to make axios fetch request to my domain name, without getting CORS errors etc.

One way I solved problem with CORS is nginx settings:

```
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
}
```

With this settings CORS errors disapeared, API stoped sending data, and in Postman i get this error:
[Postman error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MshUm.png)

And this is fetch request:

```
axios.post(`${Ip}login`,
            {
                email: email,
                password: password
            },
            {headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',            
            },
            })
          .then(function (response) {
            const stringToken = String(response.data.access_token)
            setToken(stringToken)
            sighIn(stringToken)
            setLoading(false)
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("login section")
```

Comment: Please embed the error you get to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

you can use create function of axios

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myapp.com',
  headers: { 'any': 'any' },
  timeout: 1000,
});

instance.get("/any")
```